# Console prints completely different values than what is shown on screen

Tags: java, canvas, polygon

I am following one of the examples from a book "Fundamental 2D Game Programming With Java". In that book,
one of the examples shows how to draw a polygon, in this case, it is a rectangle. I started to throw sysouts to understand better, how
that polygon drawing works.

... and those sysouts confused me completely. sysouts prints completely different values than what is shown on screen.
Values in console are without a doubt the wrong ones. But what might be causing that?

Edit: Additional information: Vector2f is a class that holds X and Y float values. It also has methods for translating, scaling, shearing and rotating the whole polygon

Here's the code that draws the polygon:

```
public static void drawPolygon(Graphics g, Vector2f[] polygon) 
{
    Vector2f P;
    Vector2f S = polygon[polygon.length - 1];

    System.out.println("Starting drawing:");

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.length; ++i) 
    {           
        //Just for testing, calls g.setColor(), nothing relevant to the problem
        setColor(i, g);                     
        P = polygon[i];

        //Debug drawing, draws the coordinates (Like in screenshot, in red color: '(322, 250)')
        g.drawString("(" + (int)S.x + ", " + (int)S.y + ")", (int)S.x, (int)(S.y));

        //Draws the rectangle, line by line in for loop (first red, then green, blue, orange)
        g.drawLine((int) S.x, (int) S.y, (int) P.x, (int) P.y);

        //System outs that prints completely different values than what is shown on screen!
        System.out.println("S.x = " + (int)S.x);
        System.out.println("S.y = " + (int)S.y);
        System.out.println("P.x = " + (int)P.x);
        System.out.println("P.y = " + (int)P.y);
        System.out.println("Drawing line from (" + (int)S.x + "," + (int)S.y + ") to (" + (int)P.x + "," + (int)P.y + ")");
        S = P;
    }

    System.out.println("End of drawing a polygon");
}
```

And here's the console output for this particular call:

```
  Starting drawing:
  S.x = -316
  S.y = -388
  P.x = -316
  P.y = -468
  Drawing line from (-316,-388) to (-316,-468)
  S.x = -316
  S.y = -468
  P.x = -236
  P.y = -468
  Drawing line from (-316,-468) to (-236,-468)
  S.x = -236
  S.y = -468
  P.x = -236
  P.y = -388
  Drawing line from (-236,-468) to (-236,-388)
  S.x = -236
  S.y = -388
  P.x = -316
  P.y = -388
  Drawing line from (-236,-388) to (-316,-388)
  End of drawing polygon
```

And here's the screenshot from Rectangle and drawString()-methods

[image: Rectangle-polygon draw]

I am really, really confused. I'm starting to run out of ideas. I'm using Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: What's `Vector2f`?  It could be an overflow issue...

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that. I added information about that class

Comment: Yes, but are the data types of `x` and `y`?

Comment: I don't suppose there's any differences if you move your System.out.printlns BEFORE the drawString call?

Comment: Tried, nothing changed. Console still prints strange values.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Graphics` uses his own coordinate system. So it might have a transformation matrix that causes these differences.

Comment: why all the (int) casting? That feels like it's just adding needless complexity here while you're debugging.

Comment: Graphics class' drawLine() and drawString() methods uses ints in their parameters, so casting is required. And obviously I'm casting them in sysouts as well because without casting they would be completely different value.